# Exporting to pdf for latex generate a .pdf_tex with several pages

Tags: inkscape, latex

I am using inkscape 0.91 on kubuntu. In a script (that I created some time ago) I use the following command line:

> inkscape -z -D --file=input.svg --export-pdf="output.pdf" --export-latex

It generates two files: output.pdf and output.pdf_tex (then I can add the image in a tex file with \input{output.pdf_tex}).

Unfortunately, it does not work anymore. The .pdf_tex file now contains several lines mentioning other pages (page=1, page=2, ...). Example:

```
  \begin{picture}(1,1.07214514)%
    \put(0.84154257,0.80899201){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{text1}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{output.pdf}}%
    \put(0.84228219,0.13316749){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{text2}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=2]{output.pdf}}%
  \end{picture}%
```

Here is a picture of the corresponding svg file ([and a link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21594703/input.svg)):

[image]

The second \includegraphics mention a second page and if I remove its line, it works fine.

Do you know why the command line behave like this with inkscape 0.91?
I can remove the additional lines manually, but there can be many of them and I often use the command (each time I modify the .svg file and want to see how it looks in my pdf file) so it is quite time consuming...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. It looks as your problem is indeed a bug and specific to your version of Inkscape (as I do not experience it). I assume that you looked at the header of the TEX file generated by Inkscape and followed the instructions (just checking)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the extra \includegraphics in output.pdf_tex does not solve the problem since each page in output.pdf contains parts of the drawing. I found a solution (proposed by Biber on launchpad.net) which uses a new definition of the "\includesvg" command:

1. Your drawings must be in the folder "./Figures/";
2. Your temporary files (".pdf", ".pdf_tex") will be added in the folder "./tmp/" (you don't need to create the "./tmp" folder it will be done automatically);
3. The 3 following commands must be placed before '\begin{document}':

% 1 - Set the graphic paths

```
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} {./.tmp/} }
```

% 2 - Command used to test if the compilation of the svg file is necessary (i.e., if the .svg file is more recent than the corresponding pdf file)

```
\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}{\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0{\immediate\write18{ [ -d ./.tmp/ ] || mkdir ./.tmp; #3}}\fi}
```

% 3 - Command that creates the ".pdf" and ".pdf_tex" from the ".svg". The workaround is in this command

```
\newcommand{\includesvg}[2][\textwidth]{\def\svgwidth{#1}\executeiffilenewer{./Figures/#2.svg}{./.tmp/#2.pdf}{\unexpanded{PDF_FILE="./.tmp/#2.pdf"; inkscape -z --file=./Figures/#2.svg --export-pdf=$PDF_FILE --export-latex; sed -i 's/\\\\/\n/g' ${PDF_FILE}_tex; MAXPAGE=$(pdfinfo $PDF_FILE | grep -oP "(?<=Pages:)\s*[0-9]+" | tr -d " ") ; sed -i "/page=$(($MAXPAGE+1))/,\${/page=/d}" ${PDF_FILE}_tex; } } \input{./.tmp/#2.pdf_tex}}
```

With these three commands an svg file can be displayed using "\includesvg" (like we would use "\includegraphics"):

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includesvg[0.5\textwidth]{My_Nice_SVG_File} %Where the file is located at: ./Figures/My_Nice_SVG_File.svg
   \caption{My_Caption]
   \label{My_Label}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I tried to clean it. Hope it is more readable now.